# Usage Stats for Site

Tags: web-analytics, statistics, usage-counters, site-usage

Is there any OOTB way to see the usage of a SharePoint site? If not what third party tool can be used? I am looking for hit per page etc.

Answer (score 5):

If you've provisioned the Web Analytics Service Application then you'll have access to some out of the box reporting functionality on a site basis.

This MSDN blog has a good overview for you

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ecm/archive/2010/03/21/introducing-web-analytics-in-sharepoint-2010.aspx

Paul.